# Защита приложения

Tags: c#, защита

Есть такой вопрос:

Есть C# приложение, нужно ещё защитить.

Слышал, что лучший способ защитить его - выполнять всю логику на удалённом сервере.

Суть в том, что там операция должна происходить раз в 10 м/c.

Если выполнять эту логику на сервере, то программа просто не успеет что-либо сделать.

Как быть?

Comment: что защищать-то?

Comment: @Grundy, есть приложение на C#. При включении, оно получает данные с базы данных и авторизирует пользователя, дальше же всё выполняется на его компьютере.

Comment: а что за операция должна происходить раз в 10 м/с?

Comment: @Grundy, чтение адресов процесса (игры)

Comment: а что конкретно нужно защищать? и от чего?

Comment: @Grundy, нужно защитить программу от обхода авторизации. Грубо говоря, чтобы её по 10 раз никто не диззассемблирил и не продавал.

Comment: Так, так. Начнем с самого главного: у вас есть официальное разрешение авторов игры на её взлом? А то, может, не о той защите вы думаете: не придётся ли защищаться в суде...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, вот и суть в том, что это чисто формально. Мне необходимо сделать защиту от диззассемблирования.

Comment: @NoName_as_Null, От дизассемблирования нельзя защититься

Comment: `Если выполнять эту логику на сервере, то программа просто не успеет что-либо сделать.` Скажите это всем ММО играм, где по сути вся логика работает на серверах, а у пользователя это по сути только клиент, который преобразовывает данные в графику.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, это хорошо, когда это происходит на сервере, а то есть такие которые с помощью клиента защищают сервер. На клиенте понаделают проверок, а сервер остается, как просто принял и выполнил. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика верная!

Основной функционал программы должен находиться на сервере, а клиент (оболочка) у пользователя.

Вы можете использовать такой подход в защите ваших приложений на **C#**

Использовать связку обфускаторов на примере:
`Confuser`, `Babel` и тому подобные.
`Net.Reactor` не имеет смысла использовать ( легко снимается ).

Для ручного шифрования есть такие библиотеки как: `mono.cecil` и `dnlib.dll` информации по ним много.